# How do I make an element appear based on a random number generator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a whack-a-mole type game for a school project. So far I've created a 2 random number generators that run based on 2 `setIntervals` that stop after a global timer, but my next steps are:

1. making elements appear, based on the id numbers I've given them, relating to the number generated.
2. make the appearing elements disappear, assuming I would be using the `.onClick()` and creating a function to add a number to the `score` variable in this instance.
3. Not displaying an item, or avoid closing it, if the same number has been generated by either generator and it hasn't been clicked. (Other solutions I had to this were to stop the generator from
   producing the same number twice or having either generator produce
   the same number.)

Is there anything I should consider besides these? 
Keep in mind I'm a total newbie and any explanations for your suggestions would be fantastic.

Here is the code I have so far:

```js
var score;
var count;
var fastcount;
var counter;
var randGen;
var randCount;
var number1;
var blob = $("td");

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#start').fadeToggle(500);

  $('#start a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    startGame($(this));
  });

});


/* Start Button Toggle */

function startGame(whichNav) {
  score = 0;
  count = 10;
  fastCount = count * 2;
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  fastCounter = setInterval(fasterTimer, 500);
  randCount1 = setInterval(randGen1, 1000);
  randCount2 = setInterval(randGen2, 500);

  var startbutton = $(whichNav.attr("href"));
  $('#start').fadeToggle(250);
  $('#timer').html(count);
  $('#score').html(score);
}


/* Game Mechanics */

/* Timer */
function timer() {
  number1 = randGen1;
  $('#number1').html(number1); //take out later
  if (count == 0) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
  }

  count = count - 1;
  $('#timer').html(count);

  if (count == 0) {
    $('#start').fadeToggle(250);
    number1 = 0;
    number2 = 0;
  };

}

function fasterTimer() {
  number2 = randGen2;
  $('#number2').html(number2); //take out later
  if (fastCount == 0) {
    clearInterval(fastCounter);
    return;
  }

  fastCount = fastCount - 1;
}


/* Number Generator */
function randGen1() {
  return parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1);
}

function randGen2() {
  return parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1);
}


/* Pop Up */
if (number1 = blob) {
  $("td .blob").show();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
}
#start {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#start a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#gameboard {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
#gameboard tr {
  width: 100%;
}
.blob {
  display: none;
}
#scoreboard {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka+One|Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="start"><a href="#start">Start</a>
    </div>
    <table id="gameboard">
      <tr id="10">
        <td id="1">
          <img class="blob" alt="tapme" src="img/snorlax.png">
        </td>
        <td id="2">
          <img class="blob" alt="tapme" src="img/snorlax.png">
        </td>
        <td id="3">
          <img class="blob" alt="tapme" src="img/snorlax.png">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="20">
        <td id="4">
          <img class="blob" alt="tapme" src="img/snorlax.png">
        </td>
        <td id="5">
          <img class="blob" alt="tapme" src="img/snorlax.png">
        </td>
        <td id="6">
          <img class="blob" alt="tapme" src="img/snorlax.png">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="30">
        <td id="7">
          <img class="blob" alt="tapme" src="img/snorlax.png">
        </td>
        <td id="8">
          <img class="blob" alt="tapme" src="img/snorlax.png">
        </td>
        <td id="9">
          <img class="blob" alt="tapme" src="img/snorlax.png">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="scoreboard">
      <div>Score: <span id="score"></span>
      </div>
      <div>Time: <span id="timer"></span>
      </div>
      <div>[DEV] Random Number 1: <span id="number1"></span>
      </div>
      <div>[DEV] Random Number 2: <span id="number2"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```